# How to calculate the odds that all items in subset A are in subset B

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a set, *S*, of 21 items, and a subset of 3 items, *T*.  I pick 10 random items from *S* into subset *U*.  How do I calculate the probability that *T* is a subset of *U*?

I brute-forced this in JavaScript and found the odds to be `40 / 323 ≈ 12.4%`.

It's been a while since I've done any more-than-basic probability/combinatorics calculations.  My intuition says it would be something like:

$$
P = 1 - \dfrac{\dfrac{(21-3)!}{(21-3-10)!}}{\dfrac{21!}{(21-10)!}} = 1 - \dfrac{\dfrac{18!}{8!}}{\dfrac{21!}{11!}} = 1 - \dfrac{33}{266} = \dfrac{233}{226} \approx 87.6\%
$$

This, ironically, is very close to `1 - 12.4%`, but that's by happenstance, as the two `12.4%`s are different values.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: The probability that you have calculated is for at least one of the items from subset $T$ to be in $U$.

$ \displaystyle 1 - \left[{18 \choose 10} / {21 \choose 10}\right] = \frac{233}{266}$

But the question reads $T$ should be subset of $U$. If all items from $T$ should be in $U$, then the approach should be as follows -

There are $21$ items. You pick $10$ items in a subset $U$ and you seek probability that $3$ specific items that make $T$ is a subset of $U$.

Given those $3$ items must be there, choose all $3$ of them and choose rest $7$ items from remaining $18$ items.

So the probability is $ \ \displaystyle {18 \choose 7} / {21 \choose 10} = \frac{12}{133}$

Comment: But... that's the wrong answer.  The answer *is* `40 / 323`.

Comment: Question says _How do I calculate the probability that T is a subset of U?_ In other words, you want all $3$ items from T to be in U, correct?

Comment: Yes.  And like I said, I brute-forced this.  I went through every combination of 10 of the 21 items, and counted how many times the three were in the 10.  It was `11440 / 92378` or `40 / 323`.

Comment: @dx_over_dt Something is wrong with your program, as this simple python program agrees with Math Lover: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY87DoMwDIb3nMIjURkIbJVYewEOgFJKqCWwUeIOPX2qpKUviX@y/X9@rXe5MjUxOs8LoIxemOcAuKzsBQZezkhWkCmojDhvh5xuyOlVUIpuSx9GCf3AJBYJaepN3UALVfaExc6ZgLeSpxx76ADpZ13hLU1jURtdgqn0USUcHZgEdmDpAvUnbHL4hJL2bjm0YNQGfB2U62r1SFJsHxU7Q8q/Zq1jfAA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Please check your code once. There may be some mistakes.

Comment: Yeah, I wonder what I did wrong with my code.  You're right though.